# How to enqueue a script on a specific URL that contains multiple parts

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, slug, wp-enqueue-style

I've tried using is_page() to pass the URL to but the page I am trying to enqueue my script on is "races/community/add" and isn't a single slug like "about-us". Is it possible to do this with is_page() or should I be approaching this in another way?

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_date_picker_styles_and_scripts', 101);
function enqueue_date_picker_styles_and_scripts() {
    if ( is_page('races/community/add') ) {
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-datepicker-css', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.css');
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-datepicker-js', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js', array('jquery'),'1.8.0', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing is jumping out at me as wrong, but yes, you should be able to pass in a path like you are to is_page(). They specifically added support for that a long while back.

Comment: It's very odd that you've included a full URL path to a page there as the parameter, `is_page` expects the slug of a post of type page, not a  URL path

Answer (score 1):

[**is_page()**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) accepts only one optional parameter `$page` which should be (`int|string|array`) representing `Page ID`, `title`, `slug`, or array of such.

On a standard WP installation your code should look like this.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_date_picker_styles_and_scripts', 101);
function enqueue_date_picker_styles_and_scripts() {
    if ( is_page('page-slug-here') ) {   // Replace page-slug-here with slug of page at races/community/add
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-datepicker-css', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.css');
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-datepicker-js', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js', array('jquery'),'1.8.0', true);
    }
}
```